# Get a list of active session from RedisSessionStateProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, azure, redis

In my Azure ASP.NET MVC website I want to display how many clients are connected to a Redis sessions state provider and how long they are active. I use the aspnet-redis-providers lib on the Azure Github.

In Redis, it creates a {[app_name]_[sessionkey}_Internal key with a SessionTimeout key with the value of the configured session timeout. The EXPIRE for that key is set to that time and when you check to TTL for the key you see the session access.

How can I use the session state provider library to access this information? If that is not possible, is there any other library I can use to query this info safely, without interfering with the session state provider?

Comment: will getting all the keys would suffice?I mean it may not give you the exact number of clients using.(one client can store many key-value pairs)

Comment: I think so, but if you can access the keys, you can also get the values I guess. It has more to do with the session state provider already having an open connection with locking etc, I would like to reuse that to do my queries

Comment: it is a key value store. am not sure if there would be a live connection of sorts which you can lock. if a client has the credentials to connect to redis cache they can always use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I was able to do. I created my own session object collection and grabbed all keys (which I am putting in DB 1) then I loop through all keys and grab the TTL.

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft;
using StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core;
using System.Linq;

    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> conn = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(
       () => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisServerMaster"]
         + "," + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisServerSlave"]
         + "," + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisOptions"])

    public class SessionObjects
    {
        public string SessionId { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? TTL { get; set; }
    }

    List<SessionObjects> lso = new List<SessionObjects>();
    var serializer = new NewtonsoftSerializer();
    StackExchangeRedisCacheClient cacheClient;
    cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(rConn, serializer, 1);
    IEnumerable<string> keys = cacheClient.SearchKeys("*");
    var db = rConn.GetDatabase(1);
    foreach (var s in keys)
    {
        SessionObjects so = new SessionObjects();
        so.SessionId = s;
        so.TTL = db.KeyTimeToLive(s);
        lso.Add(so);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, since this we moved away from Redis altogether as sessionstateprovider, because there is a minimum time between consecutive session requests (from the asp side) that can cause spikes of a queueing delay, especially when you use SPA's such as Angular which do a lot of ajax requests.

Comment: How many requests were you managing to handle a second before you saw delays? What was your system configuration and network setup? What version of Redis were you using?

Comment: @Rogier how have you fixed the issue of large ajax request queue in SPA

Comment: @ShaktiShrestha Disabling session locking should fix that issue (if your version supports it). Check this link (lock-free session state section): https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki/Configuration